# Some questions on case.energy and case.energyso in WIEN2k

Tags: density-functional-theory, spin-orbit-coupling, wien2k

In [WIEN2k](http://susi.theochem.tuwien.ac.at/), the subprogram `lapwso` will generate both `case.energy` and `case.energyso` files. What puzzle me is that  `case.energyso` has different total number of energy points compared with `case.energy`.

What is the format of these files? Which one is the true energy with SOC modified?

Answer (score 4):

From the WIEN2k manual:
`LAPWSO`:

> `lapwso` includes spin-orbit (SO) coupling in a 2nd variational
> procedure and computes eigenvalues and eigenvectors (stored in
> `case.vectorso`) using the scalar-relativistic wavefunctions from
> `lapw1`

So, after running the inputs with `-so`, the output files will be named with `so` added to the end. The next number of energies output depends upon the values in case.inso, so is different from lapw1. Note that these are just levels, not those which are filled.

> For instructions about plotting the bands with SPAGHETTI module: This
> program generates an energy bandstructure plot (postscript file
> `case.spaghetti.ps` and xmgrace file `case.bands.agr`) using the
> eigenvalues printed in `case.output1` or `case.outputso` (with switch `-so`) or `case.energy` (with switch `-enefile`).